# Is there a way to run Safari 5 or 6 on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, safari

Pretty much what the title says: Is there a way to run a version older than Safari 7 on Mavericks?

*I've seen [multi safari](http://michelf.ca/projects/multi-safari/) but that doesn't allow you to install the older versions on Mavericks*

*Also I'd need an actual running local instance, not a virtualization tunnel like browserstack*

Comment: I'm running Mountain Lion as a Virtual Box VM which works quite nicely. Might be worth going that route instead of browserstack since it is local-ish

Comment: Why do you need this - the reason will help us come to an answer

Comment: @Mark There was a need to test for a rendering glitch with html5 video that seems to only appear on Safari < 7, but browserstack has too low fps to really see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

You already know the answer based on the link you provided.

> Safari is Integral part of OS X.
>
> That is way you can not run other versions on Mavericks for example.
>
> The link you provided clearly shows the compatibility.

Quote:
 <sub>Will not work, per Multi-Safari website: "Safari normally uses the Web Kit framework found inside Mac OS X to render web pages and execute javascript. This means that if you preserve an old version of Safari to run it on a newer version of Mac OS, it will use the newer Web Kit found in the system and you will get the same results as with the newer version. Thus, you would normally need a separate installation of Mac OS X for each version of Safari you want to test a website into." –  [php_on_rails May 7 at 15:27](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22403493)</sub>

[The solution is to have appropriate OS installed (you can have multiple OS installed) as explained here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37473/can-i-use-partitions-for-multiple-os-x-installs)

Comment: As far as I can see there is no compatibility information about Mavericks.

Comment: @MaxRied great catch, do you have the information showing the mavericks compatibility with other Safari versions to make the table (this answer) up to date?

Comment: http://9to5mac.com/2013/06/10/apple-introduces-safari-7-with-design-tweaks-memory-social-improvements-and-more/ says there never was Safari 6 on Mavericks, so at least this is a hint.